# SCP with login to server and login to app user

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, scp, su

I am trying to copy files from my local machine onto a remote server. The only issue is that I must first `ssh user@host`, enter my password, then `sudo su - appuser`, and enter my password again.

I have very little permissions when logged in with my user until I move to `appuser`. Is there a way I can scp files from my local machine to a folder that is only viewable by `appuser`?

Comment: Do you have the password for `appuser`? If yes, then you can use directly the `appuser` account in the `scp` command. If not, then you can do it the other way - once you are logged in as `appuser` on the server, run a `scp` command with your local machine being the remote source (of course you need to have ssh server running on your local machine).

Comment: @raj So from my computer, I ssh into the server, login as `appuser` and then from there ssh back into my computer? Will it work like that?

Comment: You don't ssh back into your computer. Just being logged as `appuser` to the server use something like `scp localuser@yourcomputer:/path/file /serverpath`